# Can I "disable" git-clone over http?

Tags: git, http, git-clone

I'm using git to manage a tiny project.  I've been performing all of my transactions (clone, push, pull, etc) through SSH, but recently ran git-update-server-info because I wanted to experiment with running git-clone over http.  It worked great.  Cool.  Now I realize though that anyone can clone my repository over http without any credentials.  I'm vaguely aware of setting up http authentication through gitosis, but that's really not what I want.  I'd prefer to just disable http cloning entirely.

Is there a way I can tell git to only allow transactions over ssh?  Or can I undo what I did when I ran git-update-server-info to enable cloning over http in the first place?

Comment: With Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), you will have `git config protocol.<name>.allow ...`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41369667/6309)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For git repository to be available via HTTP transport, it needs to be "exported" by (any) web server.  If your repository (to be more exact its `.git` directory) is visible from outside in a web browser, then it can be cloned or fetched anonymously via HTTP protocol.  [`git update-server-info`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-server-info.html) is used to generate extra auxiliary helper information (`.git/objects/info/packs` and `.git/info/refs`) for clone (or fetch) to know what is available.

So what you need to do is to either **remove those two files (`.git/objects/info/packs` and `.git/info/refs`)**, or just make it so your repository is not available via web, perhaps by **changing permissions** in such way that user which web server runs as (usually 'nobody' or 'www', or 'apache') doesn't have access to `.git` repository.  Or **configure web server** so that it doesn't export (make visible) your repository.

The HTTP protocol is (currently) so called "dumb" protocol, meaning that it serves files as is, and access control is done by a [dumb] server, in this instance by web server you use (or by filesystem).

I guess that your repository is not exported by web server, so you don't have anything to worry about: *your repository is not available via HTTP*.

Note that it is quote usual for Git repositories to have anonymous unauthenticated read-only access, and require authentication only for writing to repository i.e. pushing (at least for open-source projects)

Comment: My .git/objects/info directory is already empty and I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way I can tell git to only allow transactions over ssh?

6 to 8 *years* later, Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) will propose a configuration to allow or disable a protocol used by Git.

```
 git config protocol.http.allow never
 git config protocol.https.allow never
 git config protocol.git.allow never
 git config protocol.file.allow never

 git config protocol.ssh.allow always
```

See [commit abcbdc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abcbdc03895ff3f00280e54af11fee92d6877044) (14 Dec 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit a768a02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a768a02265f3b8f43e37f66a0a3affba92c830c7), [commit aeae4db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeae4db1747d891dc3aee6a74508c585c321cc49), [commit f1762d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1762d772e9b415a3163abf5f217fc3b71a3b40e), [commit f962ddf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f962ddf6edb199b2611d575a75f60d20d5c137c3), [commit 85e4205](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85e42053658cf6710b84974be0ef0acf459a80d9) (14 Dec 2016) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9d540e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d540e97267fa94d9701d3e1aa5cdf2926858472), 27 Dec 2016)</sup>

This allows for a finer-grained control of what protocols are allowed for transports during clone/fetch/push have been enabled via a new configuration
mechanism.

[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d540e97267fa94d9701d3e1aa5cdf2926858472/Documentation/config.txt#L2321-L2339) now includes:

```
protocol.allow
```

> If set, provide a user defined default policy for all protocols which don't explicitly have a policy (`protocol.<name>.allow`).
> By default, if unset,
>
> - known-safe protocols (http, https, git, ssh, file) have a default policy of `always`,
> - known-dangerous protocols (ext) have a default policy of `never`, and
> - all other protocols have a default policy of `user`.
>
> Supported policies:
>
> - `always` - protocol is always able to be used.
> - `never` - protocol is never able to be used.
> - `user` - protocol is only able to be used when `GIT_PROTOCOL_FROM_USER` is either unset or has a value of 1.
>   This policy should be used when you want a protocol to be directly usable by the user but don't want it used by commands which execute clone/fetch/push commands without user input, e.g. recursive submodule initialization.

Comment: I won't change the answer, but i do appreciate you adding this info! Good to know.

Comment: @GeorgeMandis No problem. It is not released yet anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.git/objects/info/packs` and `.git/info/refs`

Comment: My .git/objects/info directory is already empty and I am still having the same problem.