# What does git update-server-info do?

Tags: git, ssh

What does git update-server-info do?  How do I know if I need it? The manual says:

> A dumb server that does not do on-the-fly pack generations must have some auxiliary information files in $GIT_DIR/info and $GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY/info directories to help clients discover what references and packs the server has. This command generates such auxiliary files.

How do I know if my server is dumb, and whether it does or does not do "on-the-fly pack generations", and whether it "must have some auxiliary information files"?

I am pushing a web app via ssh to a bare repository, then pulling from that bare repository into the web root.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348568/can-i-disable-git-clone-over-http

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Dumb server basically means accessed over HTTP.  So if you access your Git repository over `http:` or `https:` URLs, you need the `update-server-info` business, otherwise (`git:`, `ssh:`, etc.) you don't need it.

Comment: But do you have to execute git update-server-info after every push to the repo? Or just one time and it will always update the server info as the repo changes. Edit: I tried it, and it seems like the former is true.

Comment: Dmitri: You're correct, it has to be done every push. But you can use a hook to do this; in fact, the sample post-update hook has the correct command in it: `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` did it for me (make sure it's executable also)

Comment: Is anyone else dumbfounded by this? It's kind of astonishing that sharing a bare repo doesn't work when you do the obvious thing. Even worse, it *looks* like it works fine but then later turns out not to work.

Comment: @LukeMaurer, are you kidding? :) The second biggest traffic type on the net after porn is googling for git usability perversions like this. (Perhaps not even surprising, but using git is actually worse than porn, which is at least WYSIWYG, and KISS and stuff... ;-o )

Answer (score 1):

> But do you have to execute `git update-server-info` after every push to the repo?

A [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) can also use [`git update-server-info`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-server-info), updating the local catalog files needed to publish this repository (or a direct copy of it) over HTTP or FTP.

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bfce3e7b9290a8fe8c4ffc97d6b1e60e041db4f1/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> learned a new configuration to *disable* triggering of age-old `update-server-info` command, which is rarely useful these days (2022).

See [commit a2565c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2565c48e410864c049e66a64393fd6e26eb9a55), [commit 64a6151](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64a6151da7fa4b36eb2818047a9b76797e25b46e) (14 Mar 2022) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bfce3e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfce3e7b9290a8fe8c4ffc97d6b1e60e041db4f1), 23 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`repack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2565c48e410864c049e66a64393fd6e26eb9a55): add config to skip updating server info
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> By default, `git-repack` will update server info that is required by the dumb HTTP transport.
> This can be skipped by passing the `-n` flag, but what we're noticably missing is a config option to permanently disable updating this information.
>
> Add a new option "**`repack.updateServerInfo`**" which can be used to disable the logic.
> Most hosting providers have turned off the dumb HTTP protocol anyway, and on the client-side it wouldn't typically be useful either.
> Giving a persistent way to disable this feature thus makes quite some sense to avoid wasting compute cycles and storage.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2565c48e410864c049e66a64393fd6e26eb9a55/Documentation/config/repack.txt#L28-L32):

> ### `repack.updateServerInfo`
>
> If set to false, [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) will not run
> [`git update-server-info`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-server-info).
>
> Defaults to true. Can be overridden
> when true by the `-n` option of [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack).