# Git and SourceTree - installing on server issue

Tags: git, webserver, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to develop locally and then commit to the server with git.

So I have installed git on my pc and now I'm trying to access my project on my server with the SourceTree app.

I went to the repository settings and added the url, but when I try to fetch I get:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch proyectName
fatal: http://servername.com/ftp/proyectName/proyectName/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
Completed with errors, see above
```

Sure I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

In the error says that you need to execute on server:

```
git update-server-info
```

See this question to more info: [What does git update-server-info do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085402/what-does-git-update-server-info-do)

Comment: thanks for that, but I looked at this question before, but I didn't get anything out there.. what does this means:  "you need the update-server-info business"

Comment: Is probably a configuration mistake when you create the repository on the SourceTree, if you don't run the command in the answer on the server you can not access throw `http:` or `https:`. Try to change and access with `git:` or exec the command on the server.

Comment: when I try to access with git: I get git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch projectName 
fatal: unable to connect to serverName.com:
serverName.com[IP]: errno=Connection refused. How can I exec the command on the server?