# Git through https on debian server

Tags: git, apache, http, https, debian

I'm trying to set up my own git server through https with apache2 in debian. I configured all and I can access my git repo through my browser, but I cannot clone it. It is not recognized as a git repo.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message your are getting? Can you "git status" ?

Comment: i use GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true for testing only, and i get fatal: https://192.168.1.100/git/siper.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository? and git status say: "this operation mus be run in a work tree" when i ran that command inside the repo folder

Comment: What commands did you use to initialize repo on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `git update-server-info` in each repo, on the remote server.

For more info see 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-server-info
and
 [What does git update-server-info do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085402/what-does-git-update-server-info-do)

Comment: i did it but nothing happens, i still getting the same error when i try to clone the repository in my browser when I enter https://192.168.1.100 shows me the parent directory of my repos, there is just one folder named siper.git which is my actual repo, but when i try to clone it with git clone https://192.168.1.100/siper.git i can't beacause it is not recognized as a repository