# Git can't push data - permission denied or `could not determine hash algorithm`

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, plesk

Today I ran into heavy problems with `git` and don't know how to proceed. On Plesk I created a new repository and tried to connect it to my local computer (to push data from local to remote). I did this several times before on other domains but on the same server without problems.

I tried using `fork` and `VSCode`.

With `fork` and SSH I get this error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
ssnadmin@mydomain: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The SSH access works. So I can open a SSH to ssnadmin@mydomain and the password is correct. What is the problem then?

But with `VSCode` and HTTPS this error:

```
[info] fatal: https://ngx.speedskatingnews.info/plesk-git/ngx.git/info/refs not valid: could not determine hash algorithm; is this a git repository?
```

What does this message mean `could not determine hash algorithm`?

I already retried/reinstalled a few times but have no idea what I can do to fix this problem. Please does anybody has a solution?

Comment: See if you have multiple ssh versions: perhaps the one you use for separate testing works, but the one Git runs doesn't. If so, set `core.sshCommand` to use the one that works. (The HTTPS error indicates that you haven't run the https ref builder, perhaps; this isn't required for ssh.)

Comment: @torek it's the same SSH, but to be honest I'm not really fit in git. So how and where can I set this `core.sshCommand` and what is the https ref builder? But for other repositories it work well...

Comment: `git config --global core.sshCommand "c:/path/to/ssh.exe"` for instance. The refs file is built by `update-server-info`; see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2085402/1256452).

Comment: Thx for the info. Unfortunately it didn't solved my problem