# What is the easiest way to tell if a non-bare remote git repository is dirty?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When a deployment is in production, it can sometimes be difficult to justify pulling, just so you can merge and push changes back up (we have a fast forward only policy on our central repository).

However, I do want those changes to be merged up sooner rather than later, so that new deployments can benefit from the fixes. As such, I pull changes from the production deployment into a non-production deployment, and do the pull-merge-push from there.

I have set up a series of remotes, so that I can easily pull in changes from lots of remotes in one go, but that only helps if the working directories are clean.

Since we have dozens of repositories per deployment, dozens of deployments, and minor fixes may have been applies in any of them, I was wondering if there were an easy way to tell if a remote has a clean working directory when pulling from it, and flag up when a remote was dirty.

Definitions:

- Deployment: A series of git repositories deployed using [buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/), cloned from our central (bare) repositories.
- Production: A deployment which is running live. It is expected that production deployments will not be changed any more than is absolutely necessary, i.e. essential bug fixes only.
- Non-production: A deployment which is not running live, where we are free to pull, merge, push and change branches without the risk of [e-git messing up permissions bits and causing a live system to stop working](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366366).

Comment: No....?  Can you explain your workflow a little bit?  It sounds like your production deployment is its own repository?  And you pull from *that*?  But that people might make changes without any sort of process and thus make the working directory dirty?  Am I understanding what you're asking?

Comment: Essentially Yes. I hope my definitions help @EdwardThomson.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no hook on a remote repo side for git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2794694/6309), so that means you need to:

- have a job monitoring the state of the working directory (see "[Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659808/6309)" for the script executed by this job)
- disable clone/pull/fetch when the working tree is dirty (one way, for instance, is illustrate din "[Can I “disable” `git-clone` over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348632/6309)")

This isn't a full-proof mechanism though, and a more robust way would be:

- For each non-production repo, have a *bare* non-production repo in addition of the non-bare one
- a hook in the non-bare repo in order to sync the bare repo (pull any new commit done in the non-bare to the bare one)
- pulling only from the bare "non-production" repos (bare rpeo means no working directory, so no issue with "dirty" state).